# submitting form after validating field with out any submit button

Tags: ajax

my requirement is to submit the form after validating phone number field after all the validations are gone success i want to submit form directly without any submit button are anchor

Answer (score 0):

You can try simple js as:

```
document.formName.action="actionServlet";
document.formName.submit();
```

and in ajax you can try:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","actionUrl",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function validate_fields_and_submit() {
  // Validate fields here.

  // Then submit form.
  document.forms["myform"].submit();
}
```